# Is .Net 4 environment make interfere with Documentum 5.3 SP3

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-2.0, documentum

I have a **documentum 5.3 SP3** content server installed on a machine And one **.net application** is also installed on the same machine

current .NET version is 2.0

and i want to install the .NET version 4.0 on that machine.

> So, I want to know if that install will in any way interfere with
>   Documentum?

Answer (score 0):

You can install different versions of .Net frameworks on a machine and everything should work fine. The documentum content server does not need .Net framework installed. So I suppose you are using something 3rd party/homebrew component, maybe you should ask the developers of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all major versions of .Net concurrently, so there should be no issue.  This is completely independent of Documentum.